# What is the appropriate way to create a new user, switch to that user, then delete the old user

Tags: users, delete

In a new server, I want to create a user, switch to that user, and then delete the old user completely. I currently do the following:

```bash
# create new user
sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash newuser
sudo passwd newuser
sudo usermod -aG sudo newuser

# set up user
su - newuser

# delete old user
sudo deluser --remove-home olduser
```

When I run the final command, I am warned with `user olduser is currently used by process xxx. returned error code 8. Exiting`. I believe I can `pkill` the user's processes, but what is the industry standard way of performing these actions?

It appears that `sudo userdel -r -f olduser` works, but it gives logs that don't appear to be ideal:

```
userdel: user olduser is currently used by process xxx
userdel: olduser mail spool (/var/mail/olduser) not found
```

Comment: You will need to log out of the olduser session and log in again under newuser. You can then delete the olduser account.

Comment: I believe `su - newuser` achieves the logging in, so can I just log out of the old session from there?

Comment: No. `su - newuser` creates a new shell and the old user still has processes running. Killing all processes owned by olduser will kill the `su`. If this is a console session (not a gui), then `exec su - newuser` would work.

Comment: I see thank you. As a followup, it looks like `sudo userdel -r -f olduser` does in fact kill the process of the `olduser` and delete the `olduser` AND still allow me to use the shell as `newuser`. Does this match what you are saying? If so, what is the difference between this, and the `exec su - newuser` you suggested?

Comment: Even if I use `exec su - newuser`, a `sudo userdel -r -f olduser` still gives `userdel: user olduser is currently used by process xxxx`. Would you expect this?

Comment: are doing you doing this remotly ?
if yes , that explain a lot 
run `ps faux`  and you will see a sshd process that belong olduser is the parent of your current shell

Comment: userdel delete files only not user's procceses https://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel. su just change user's id. So logout then login  and del old user

Comment: Also as other instructed you, observe process tree with something like htop to understand process setup and why the directory is held even after exec. You can edit you htop columns to see real and effective user IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost doing it right, but you are missing two important steps in the middle, that warrant full articles on their own. I will provide these steps just as short descriptions, I believe you are capable and able to figure them out by searching the net.

And no, as you already discovered `su - newuser` will not work (at least on most modern distros) no matter how hard you wish for it. It is too complicated to explain all the reasons.

```
# create new user
sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash newuser
sudo passwd newuser
sudo usermod -aG sudo newuser

# 1 !!! IMPORTANT STEP !!!
# login on different VT or ssh connection into new user

# 2 !!! IMPORTANT STEP !!!
# logout all sessions for old user, and terminate all the 
# processes it may have running after the loguts 
# (for example tmux/screen sessions, service processes and whatnot)

# delete old user from the pristine newuser session
sudo deluser --remove-home olduser
```

Comment: For #2, does `pkill -u olduser` achieve the goal of terminating all the processes it may have running after the logout?

Comment: It used to, but these days the issue is more complicated, and would warrant more detailed articles. On simple system that you solely are using, this should work. The complicating factors are windowsification and containerisation. Windowsification is introduction of systemd, containerisation is docker, podman and friends. Traditionally system APIs are used to query for id/user map, and everything happens in single namespace.

Comment: Depending on the system "plug-in" loadout, the user name/id might be coming from compeletely different source than the system, and then you need to delete the user there. Also some modern systemd components, especially 3rd party, might be caching uid/name pairs, and not realize that user has been deleted, and try for example to spawn processes under them, while you have deleted it in-between the two invocations. So `pkill -u olduser` might work only temporarily in such cases.

Comment: It gets even more complicated, if you take containers into account, especially root ones, or user ones especially if they map their user ids to host user ids and similar situations, especially in bind mounted volumes and such. In such cases in-container user in different namespace might or might not map to your deleted user on a host. This is often controlled by whoever setup the container, so if it is not you, it might be out of your control.

Comment: For example: in-container process might be running, holding open file descriptors to files, that exist inside of a subdirectory, somewhere inside the home, of the user you are deleting, because it was bound into it. While some people will shriek, that this is convoluted example, in practice it happens more often than not, way more often than it should. Only operational experience will teach you stuff like this. Even if you kill with `pkill -u olduser` those file descriptors will be held and depending on mount namespace propagations, deleted user home could or could not be deleted as a result.

Comment: Thus you have to be diligent, inspect and terminate everything that could be using "deleted user" resources beforehand. In practice, ancient unix tradition is to NOT DELETE users at all, but to disable them, because that way you can always map their files across systems later: it is much easier to see file on a filesystem owned by "baduser" and check the modif. date, than to see it as owned by "156332" and scratch your head, who could have been that "156332" a year later.